# When a recover() is no-op?

Tags: go, defer-keyword

refer:  https://go101.org/quizzes/panic-recover-1.html

```
package main

import "fmt"

func ExamplePanicGo101_1() {
    defer func() {
        fmt.Print(recover()) // catch panic(1)
    }()

    defer func() {
        defer fmt.Print(recover()) // catch panic(2)
        defer panic(1)
        recover() // no-op - B, should be called inside deferred function,
    }()

    defer recover() // no-op - A, should be called inside deferred function,
    panic(2)
    // Output:
    // 21
}
```

The test passes.

**Questions:**

- I can understand `no-op - A` is no-op, since it's not called inside deferred function, but how `no-op - B` is no-op? Since it's called inside deferred function, I though it should catch the `panic(2)`, but not.

Comment: Does this equivalent program help to understand? https://go.dev/play/p/4rnMr8N2wP1

Comment: Ok, that helps, so this line `defer fmt.Print(recover()) // catch panic(2)`, the param `recover()` of `fmt.Print()` is evaluated first, that makes it catch the `panic(2)`.

Comment: Yes. Arguments to deferred functions are evaluated at the time they are deferred, not when the function eventually executes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may have missed the following [point re `defer`](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Defer_statements):

> Each time a "defer" statement executes, the function value and parameters to the call are evaluated as usual and saved anew but the actual function is not invoked.

So when executing

```
defer fmt.Print(recover()) // catch panic(2)
defer panic(1)
recover() // no-op - B, should be called inside deferred function,
```

the steps are:

- Evaluate `recover()` and, effectively, `defer fmt.Print(2)` (because `recover()` evaluates to `2`).
- `defer panic(1)`
- `recover()` - noop as there is no active panic
- execute deferred `panic(1)`
- execute deferred `fmt.Print(2)` ([remember that](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Handling_panics) "Any functions deferred by F are then executed as usual")

The following [example](https://go.dev/play/p/zAUy1HCkSEh) may help:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    defer func() {
        fmt.Println(recover()) // catch panic(1)
    }()

    defer func() {
        fmt.Println("a")
        defer fmt.Println(fmt.Println("a1")) // The "a1" will print between a and b (note `3 nil` will be printed later, this is the return from the inner fmt.Println)
        defer fmt.Println(recover())         // catch panic(2)
        fmt.Println("b")
        defer panic(1)
        fmt.Println("c")
        recover() // no-op - B, should be called inside deferred function,
    }()

    defer recover() // no-op - A, should be called inside deferred function,
    panic(2)
    // Output:
    // a
    // a1
    // b
    // c
    // 2
    // 3 <nil>
    // 1
}
```